# Can SQLAlchemy handle unknown polymorphic identities?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 parts of my app: ingestion and display. Ideally, both of these would always be at the same version of the code, but alas, reality doesn't allow perfectly simultaneous deployments. Also, it's useful for us to work on data ingestion before rolling out the corresponding frontend.

The problem I have is that I'm using SQLAlchemy's polymorphic identities, and when I add a new class on the backend, the frontend suddenly doesn't know what to do with it. Here's a specific example. Say I have this code:

```
class Campaign(BaseData):
    __tablename__ = 'campaign'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'parent',
        'polymorphic_on': description
    }

class SubCampaign(Campaign):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'sub'
    }
```

Then, I add this new class:

```
class OtherCampaign(Campaign):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'other'
    }
```

When I insert some rows into the db with the `description` column set to `other`, they throw an error:

```
No such polymorphic_identity 'other' is defined
```

Is there a way to work around this? I'd be happy to ignore those rows.

Comment: you need to define that model on the "front" and "back", assuming these are two separate applicaitons consuming the same DB.  Otherwise what kind of object do you want returned?

Comment: They're the same application, consuming the same DB. The problem is the deployments might drift from each other. Does it just mean I always have to define the new class in both before doing any data inserts? (The real answer might be that I'm using the wrong pattern by cramming this into polymorphic identities, but re-writing will take a bit of time, so I'm kicking that can down the road as far as possible.)

Comment: by "separate" yes i mean deployments.  if your un-updated deployment queries for an "other" what kind of object do you want it to get back?   if that deployment knows nothing about "OtherCampaign" then it can't just make that up.  There are ways to configure this so that it falls back to some fixed object type for unknown values.    Or maybe you don't want to query for those unknown types in that deployment, there's ways to do that too.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it has to do something. I'd like it to ignore those rows. How would I set that up?

Comment: well the easiest way is to filter them.   Since you do know the names you do want locally it would be like "query.filter(Campaign.description.in_(['sub', 'goodname1', 'goodname2'])".  now that's kind of literal, so it depends on how you're doing queries and how you'd want to automate that, or not.  plus you can get the names from Campaign.__mapper__.polymorphic_identities if that helps...

Comment: That'll do it. I'm not crazy about doing this for every query, but I could probably define a helper if it gets bad. Thanks! I'm going to post this as an answer, but if you want the credit, I'd be happy to accept one you write up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion with zzzeek in the comments, I ended up changing the query on the read side to only request valid data. Instead of:

```
rows =  session.query(Campaign).all()
```

I'm doing

```
valid_descriptions = [m.polymorphic_identity for m in 
                      Campaign.__mapper__.polymorphic_iterator()]
rows =  session.query(Campaign)\
                .filter(Campaign.description.in_(valid_descriptions))\
                .all()
```